# xpath in selenium took 2 min to execute

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automation, selenium

I have a table and I am trying to get the no of rows in table. But following statement took too much time to execute. 
Dim NumOfRows As Integer = selenium.GetXpathCount("//table[@id='Group']/tbody/tr")

any idea what is taking too long

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm guessing you must be using IE? The xpath performance is horrific for things like this, and you'll no doubt run into more performance issues. My advice is to simply get the entire DOM out of selenium and parse it yourself with html agility.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/